# Guessing a number knowing only if the number proposed is lower or higher?

Tags: algorithm, math

I need to guess a number. I can only see if the number I'm proposing is lower or higher. Performance matters a whole lot, so I thought of the following algorithm:

Let's say the number I'm trying to guess is 600.

- I start out with the number 1000 (or for even higher performance, the average result of previous numbers).
- I then check if 1000 is higher or lower than 600. It is higher.
- I then divide the number by 2 (so that it is now 500), and check if it is lower or higher than 600. It is lower.
- I then find the difference and divide it by 2 in the following way to retrieve a new number: (1000 + 500) / 2. The result is 750. I then check that number.

And so on.

Is this the best approach or is there a smarter way of doing this? For my case, every guess takes approximately 500 milliseconds, and I need to guess quite a lot of numbers in as low time as possible.

I can roughly assume that the average result of previous guesses is close to the upcoming numbers too, so there's a pattern there which I can use for my own advantage.

Comment: I would ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com/ as it's not really a programming question.

Comment: what if you start lower than the number, what is your next guess?

Comment: "A number" is _really_ broad. Are there any constraints regarding what "A number" can be?

Comment: what if the number is higher than your first guess?  What is your second guess then?  do you just add a random number?

Comment: is there a need for the evolutionary-algorithm tag here ?

Comment: If it is a real number, you can use active learning techniques. You can model the unknown change from x(n-1) to x(n) as a random walk, and find the next probing number that would minimize the uncertainty for your target #, for example. Of course, this may not be the "fastest", since comparison operation is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes `binary search` is the most effective way of doing this. `Binary Search` is what you described. For a number between 1 and N `Binary Search` runs in `O(log(n))` time.

So here is the algorithm to find a number between 1-N

```
int a = 1, b = n, guess = average of previous answers;

while(guess is wrong) {

    if(guess lower than answer) {a = guess;}
    else if(guess higher than answer) {b = guess;}

    guess = (a+b)/2;

} //Go back to while
```

Comment: That's not taking the final paragraph into account though.

Comment: There now the first guess is the average rather than the middle of the range. From there the algorithm is the same

Comment: I don't think it necessarily should be. For example, it could absolutely make sense to take the distribution of previous results into account.

Comment: I think that it's possible to do better than a simple binary search (even with using the average as the first guess) but I don't think it's possible to do better than `O(log(n))` so asymptotically it's equivalent. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're taking the best possible approach without the extra information - it's a *binary search*, basically.

Exactly how you *use* the "average result of previous guesses" is up to you; it would suggest biasing the results towards that average, but you'd need to perform analysis of just how indicative previous results are in order to work out the best approach. Don't just use the average: use the complete distribution.

For example, if all the results have been in the range 600-700 (even though the hypothetical range is up to 1000) with an average of 670, you might *start* with 670 but if it says "guess higher" then you would probably want to choose a value between 670 and 700 as your next guess, rather than 835 (which is *very likely* to be higher than the real result).

I suggest you log all the results from previous enquiries, so you can then use that as test data for alternative approaches.

Comment: I think unless there is some reason to believe that there is some structure to the numbers being guessed (i.e. they are not purely random), then the "average result of previous numbers" is a waste of time.

Comment: @Matt: The "reason to believe" it is that the question explicitly states it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, binary search starting at the middle point of the range is the optimal strategy. However, you have additional specific information which may make this a suboptimal strategy. This depends critically in what exactly "close to the average of the previous results" means.

If numbers are close to the previous average then dividing by 2 in the second step is not optimal.

Example: Previous numbers 630, 650, 620, 660. You start with 640.

Your number is actually closer. Imagine that it is 634.

The number is lower. If in the second step you divide by 2, you get 320, thus losing any advantage about the previous average numbers.

You should analyze the behaviour further. It may be optimal, in your specific case, to start at the **mean** of the N previous numbers and then add or substract some quantity related to the **standard deviation** of the previous numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, binary search (your algorithm) is correct here. However there is one thing missing in the standard binary search:

For binary search you normally need to know the maximum and minimum between which you are searching. In case you do not know this, you have to iteratively find the maximum in the beginning, like so:

- Start with zero
- if it is higher than the number searched, zero is your maximum and you have to find a minimum
- if it is lower than the number searched, zero is your minimum and you have to find a maximum
- You can search for your maximum/minimum by starting at 1 or -1 and always multiplying by two  until you find a number which is greater/smaller

When you always multiply by two, you will be much faster than when you search linearly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the range of possible values? If yes, always start in the middle and do exactly what you describe.

Comment: I can only assume the range of possible values given previous results and the average of that, but I can never be sure

Comment: If you can never be sure, we the answerers can never be sure about our answers, either.

Answer (score 0):

A standard binary search between 0 and N(N is the given number) will give you the answer in logN time.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 1, b = n+1, guess = average of previous answers;

while(guess is wrong) {

    if(guess lower than answer) {a = guess;}
    else if(guess higher than answer) {b = guess;}

    guess = (a+b)/2;

} //Go back to while
```

You got to add +1 to n else you can never get n since it's an int.

Answer (score 0):

I gave an answer to a similar question ["Optimal algorithm to guess any random integer without limits?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4513275/435176)

Actually, provided there algorithm not just searches for the conceived number, but it estimates a *median* of the distribution of the number that you may re-conceive at each step! And also the number could be even from the real domain ;)